# Mermaid ER diagram styling

Tags: markdown, entity-relationship, erd, mermaid

I want to draw an ER diagram with Mermaid. But I can't find out how to style the box to make it with different colors.

I know it's possible to set the theme color, but I can't do it to each box. I've tried different syntaxes and found some information on the offical documentation, but I can't figure out how to use them.[official docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6OlG.png)
I want to make it like this:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcXkY.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example ([Mermaid Live link](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNqtk0tzgjAUhf9KJjPugJGHiDjdtF22K3cVOxPhqhlDwsQ4SoH_3gA-sK1s6i4595xvcnPnFjgWCeAQDwYF5VSFqIg4QhFWG0ghwqE-JrAie6YibHRKL7NZXZ3XUi1aIC0JjCgq-G5DszeyBIYKtKKMhWjJSLydokozUG_iWRwvocOGKvgjBFxRlXedjK43ai1J3rrP5jlNPp9at7kTKSxQbxyATyt0J5_miizZXUQmDgnIJdvDfQThQn-d7OdQvm0ILWAR8aoaDCIO8pUS3WHa6nU3DcdGZWmaZXlVnHpk5_xv36mPrqn7rh5bh1W0SqMqSfkaxYLZHe9txelUqh8w5wGw02MfQLr5iv_jsIFTkCmhid6wnsXSU9ZWsldilvMYhyvCdmDgfZYQBafBX1RIqBLyvV3bZnsNnBH-IcTVo-84LPARh2bg-pbj-XYwnrj-MPAMnGt1NLItdzyZDIf-aOx6rl8Z-KshOJbnBo5tj7yhHXie41TfJRdJYg))

[image]

Note, that in the live link, I put the init directly in the code rather than the config.  This is because it makes it easier if I want to copy it somewhere else.

```
%%{init: {
  "theme": "default",
  "themeCSS": [
    ".er.relationshipLabel { fill: black; }", 
    ".er.relationshipLabelBox { fill: white; }", 
    ".er.entityBox { fill: lightgray; }",
    "[id^=entity-some] .er.entityBox { fill: lightgreen;} ",
    "[id^=entity-mytable] .er.entityBox { fill: powderblue;} ",
    "[id^=entity-anothertable] .er.entityBox { fill: pink;} "
    ]
}}%%
```

The first three settings set the default css, the last three are specific to a table using a pattern.

Note that when testing in Mermaid Live and maybe some other implementations, you need to prefix the table name/pattern with `entity-`, but in some other implementations (e.g. Gitlab), you would need to remove that prefix to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been waiting for the correct format for several days lol

Answer (score 0):

The Mermaid syntax does not currently support custom colors for ER diagrams without custom CSS.

There's an open issue about this, and this comment provides a solution when you can control the diagram source and the CSS for the theme: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2673#issuecomment-1522470695

Answer (score -1):

```
erDiagram
    CUSTOMER {
        id INT PK
        email VARCHAR
        password VARCHAR
    }

    BUYER {
        id INT PK
    }

    BUSINESS_CLIENT {
        id INT PK
    }

    ADMINISTRATOR {
        id INT PK
    }

    PRODUCT {
        id INT PK
    }

    CART {
        id INT PK
        customer_id INT FK
    }

    ORDER {
        id INT PK
        customer_id INT FK
    }

    REVIEW {
        id INT PK
        buyer_id INT FK
        product_id INT FK
    }

    WISHLIST {
        id INT PK
        buyer_id INT FK
        product_id INT FK
    }

    SUPPORT_TICKET {
        id INT PK
        customer_id INT FK
    }

    USER_ACCOUNT {
        id INT PK
    }

    PRODUCT_CATALOG {
        id INT PK
    }

    PRODUCT_CATEGORY {
        id INT PK
    }

    SPECIFICATION {
        id INT PK
        product_id INT FK
    }

    ORDER_SHIPMENT {
        id INT PK
        business_client_id INT FK
    }

    DELIVERY_ADDRESS {
        id INT PK
        business_client_id INT FK
    }

    INVOICE {
        id INT PK
        business_client_id INT FK
    }

    ANALYTICS {
        id INT PK
        business_client_id INT FK
    }

    WEBSITE_TRAFFIC {
        id INT PK
    }

    USER_ACTIVITY {
        id INT PK
    }

    SALES_REPORT {
        id INT PK
    }

    CUSTOMER ||--|{ BUYER
    CUSTOMER ||--|{ BUSINESS_CLIENT
    CUSTOMER ||--|{ ADMINISTRATOR
    CUSTOMER ||--|| CART
    CUSTOMER ||--|| ORDER
    CUSTOMER ||--|| SUPPORT_TICKET
    CUSTOMER ||--|| USER_ACCOUNT

    BUYER }|--|{ REVIEW
    BUYER }|--|{ WISHLIST

    BUSINESS_CLIENT ||--|| ORDER_SHIPMENT
    BUSINESS_CLIENT ||--|| DELIVERY_ADDRESS
    BUSINESS_CLIENT ||--|| INVOICE
    BUSINESS_CLIENT ||--|| ANALYTICS

    PRODUCT_CATALOG ||--|| PRODUCT
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY ||--|| PRODUCT
    PRODUCT ||--|| SPECIFICATION

    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| PRODUCT_CATALOG
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| PRODUCT_CATEGORY
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| SPECIFICATION
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| ORDER
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| SUPPORT_TICKET
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| USER_ACCOUNT
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| WEBSITE_TRAFFIC
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| USER_ACTIVITY
    ADMINISTRATOR ||--|| SALES_REPORT
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**